# How java effectively stores 4 byte char arrays

Tags: java, encoding, char

Please help me understand how java stores strings and char arrays.
In java `Character.SIZE` returns `16` and most of the answers on stackoverflow and web state that character in java is 16 bits (Obviously, since it uses UTF-16 internally), however UTF-16 can't fit everything in 2 bytes. For example Chinese.

```java
char c = '的';
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Character.toString(c).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)));
```

This piece of code prints  `[-2, -1, 118, -124]`, meaning a char was 4 bytes long. Does that mean that Strings in java that consist of `char[]` array, take 4 bytes for every char. That'd take too much space, so I assume that's not what happens. It must be that char has variable length. If that's so, it's impossible to store char[] as a long list of bytes in ram without specifying length of each individual char first. And that'd take too much space also.

So what's the actual size of a char in Java. And how is it stored in ram if it has variable length?

Comment: The actual size of a `char` is 16 bits. Some characters are represented by more than one `char`. That is `char` != real-life character.

Comment: Why do you think that `的` doesn't fit in UTF-16? [It's UTF-16 representation is `0x7684`](https://ideone.com/lH4vRN), which is less than half the max value which can be represented by a char

Comment: @Michael, why does my piece of code prints an array of 4 bytes then? Now it's even more confusing... May be I provided a bad character for my example, but still, some `UTF-16` characters can't fit in 2 bytes. They're 3 or 4 bytes. That's how Unicode works. Java is still able to store them under single `char` primitive that's supposed to have 2 bytes length.

Comment: @maklas, try using `UTF_16BE` instead of `UTF_16`. That's a BOM mark you got in the first two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The character you are using is a 2 byte character.

The first two bytes in the encoded byte array are UTF-16 [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

An actual 4 byte unicode code point would be represented as two chars.

```
final char[] chars = Character.toChars(0x2070E);
System.out.println(chars.length);
```